# How to read proprietary Windows LDM partition (or convert to NTFS) on Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, windows, gparted, ntfs

I removed Windows 10 from my 240GB SSD to use Ubuntu 21.10 as default system.

But I can't read a partition in my 1TB HD which I created using Windows.

The partition I am referring is was on a 1TB HD which I used only to store files. The partition files simply disappeared and now it is named as "Windows" inside Ubuntu with parition type "LDM" (?).

**What is the best way to get access to this partition?**

Comment: Have you used (in Windows) anything else than basic partitions? Did you had Bitlocker enabled? Did you disabled Fast Startup before removing Windows?

Comment: Hey, no BitLocker. I have disabled "Fast Startup" on BIOS after I have installed Ubuntu.

Comment: There's no Fast Startup in "BIOS" (actually UEFI which replaced BIOS a decade ago), there's "Fast Boot" which is immaterial for the problem in question. Again , if it wasn't clear the hint above, dynamic disks or whatever Microsoft calls it now it ISN'T compatible with anything else than Windows. Basic NTFS partitions are supported, nothing else. And if Fast Startup - a WINDOWS feature unrelated with the firmware - wasn't disabled then now the partition may at best be mounted as read-only.

Comment: Open a terminal. Run `sudo fdisk -l`. Omit all of the /dev/loop entries (those are snaps). Post the (complete) remaining entries in your Question above. The information we need to answer your question is in that output.

Comment: Here the result of 'fdisk -l' https://pastebin.com/jyArqR5E

Comment: The comment above explicitly asked you to omit all /dev/loop and you didn't, but OK. It's just that when one asks for help one should make it easy for other to offer help. You may need this: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ldmtool.1.html (no, I don't know how to use it, never did). Better to open that drive in a Windows system, backup all the files you need and then, in Ubuntu, format it to a proper file system. Linux has no tools to error correct NTFS partitions therefore those should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Solved. Installing Windows to read the LDM partition, and making the backup of the data. Thanks @ChanganAuto and @ user535733 =)